# (Java) Data Structure for agenda-like program?

Tags: android, data-structures

In a nutshell, I've parsed data like this from XML:

```
root ---- date1 ---- time 1 ----item 1 ---- prop 1 --- a
       |          |          |           |         |-- b
       |          |          |           |    
       |          |          |           |- prop 2
       |          |          |    
       |          |          |--item 2
       |          |
       |          |- time 2
       |
       |
       |- date2 ---- time 1
```

each `item` has several properties (like item1 has prop1 and prop2)

each `time` has several `item`s

each `date` has several `time`s

root has several `date`s as its children

And I want to use this data:

Be able to show user the content within each date. e.g. if `date1` is current date, then shows user each `item` sorted by `time`, just display these data kind like Android Google Calendar's Agenda View.

So may I ask what data structure should I use to achieve this?

The possible candidates I've thought are:

1. Nested HashMap, like `HashMap<Time, HashMap<item1, HashMap<prop1, a>>>;`
2. SQL database, create table for each `time`, then put `item` in row, `prop` in column

It's totally ok for this app not to strictly keep the tree-like structure when store the data, so I prefer SQL database, may I ask you guy for possible better solutions?

This app is going to running on Android, thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

My thought of the database structure:

create database table for each date;

Then in each DB table:

```
        time    prop1    prop2    prop3
item1
item2
...
```

Then maybe later I can retrieve `item`s by using `select` on `time` basis.

**UPDATE2**
I need to create table for dates because some of the item may be the same. Please imagine you put two same meetings on different days in a week. I can't create tables for each `item` because it is difficult to extract those info from original XML than just create `date` tables and put them in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one table for all and us a date column to retrieve data as you wish. you don't need to make it complicated like creating tables for all dates.

Comment: Thx for the advice. I need to create table for dates because some of the item may be the same (like you put same meeting 3 days a week on your agenda, thus the item will have some same properties)

Comment: use timestamp and it wont be same time, but it will be same date. you can group by date by this way. still you don't have to create tables

Comment: Will it significantly drag down the performance when creating tables? May I know the reason? thanx :)

Comment: A database ment to be created and designed once.And it is easy to implement.I dont know how will it efect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to create a DAO (Data Access Object) that would be responsible for taking the object that resulted from parsing the XML and storing all the data on SQLite correctly. The DAO would also be responsible for re-making the object from the SQLite data.

Keep in mind that this translation won't be as easy as you mentioned though. You said "create table for each time, then put item in row, prop in column". This is not a standard DB model, as usually you don't create a table for each instance of a given entity.

Start by analyzing what entities you have (e.g., date, time, item) and then analyze the relationship between them (e.g., a data contains one or more time, a time contains one or more items, etc). Usually each entity will become a table on your DB, and relationships will either go inside an existing table (as a reference to other tables) or they will have their own table. You can read more about this approach here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Comment: thanks for the quick pop. Or maybe I can create table for each date, and use `item` as row, `time`, `prop` as columns? It is okay not to keep the tree-like structure in DB, so may i ask what's your opinion?

Comment: I've updated my questions, please refer to the new version :-)